# requirejs r.js errors after optimization in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm struggling to get requirejs to work after optimizing with r.js It works fine pre optimization,

**errors in browser:**

> main.js:71 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

in included plugin mCustomScrollbar to main.js

> factory(jQuery,window,document);
>
> file:///home/atm/public/www-build/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   require.js:2 Uncaught Error: Script error for "mCustomScrollbar"
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror.

html:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['main'],function(){
      require(['page/page1']);
    });
</script>
```

main.js config file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths : {
        page: 'page',

        'jquery' : ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min',
                    'jquery-2.2.1.min'],
        'mCustomScrollbar' : 'jquery.mCustomScrollbar',
        'jquery-mousewheel' : 'jquery.mousewheel.min'
    }, 
    shim : {
        'mCustomScrollbar' : {
                                deps : ['jquery','jquery-mousewheel']
                            }
    }
});
```

page1.js

```
define(['jquery','mCustomScrollbar'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#content-3").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollButtons:{enable:true},
            theme:"dark-thick"
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

build.js config

```
({
    appDir: "../www",
    baseUrl: 'js/', // relative to appDir
    dir: "../www-build",
    mainconfigfile: '../www/js/main.js',
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            include: ['jquery','mCustomScrollbar']
        },
        {
            name: 'page/page1',
            include: ['page/page1'],
            exclude: ['main']
        }
    ],
    paths: {
        'jquery': "empty:",
        'mCustomScrollbar' : 'jquery.mCustomScrollbar',
        'jquery-mousewheel' : 'jquery.mousewheel.min'
    },
    shim : {
        'mCustomScrollbar' : { deps : ['jquery','jquery-mousewheel'] }
    },
    optimize: "none",
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    removeCombined: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> main.js:71 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

This is likely because `jquery-mousewheel` loaded before `jquery`. You can try to config dependencies for `jquery-mousewheel` like this

```
shim : {
    'mCustomScrollbar' : {
        deps : ['jquery','jquery-mousewheel']
    },
    'jquery-mousewheel' : { 
        deps : ['jquery']
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem partially, no includes in to main config mCustomScrollbar                                       'mCustomScrollbar' : "empty:",

Answer (score 0):

i find inside script comment :

```
* load jquery-mousewheel plugin (via CDN) if it's not present or not loaded via RequireJS (works when * load jquery-mousewheel plugin (via CDN) if it's not present or not loaded via RequireJS
```

maybe is problem optimize js files with one file

Answer (score 0):

ok now is work fully, 
I fixed the problem, include into plugin mCustomScrollbar

```
 define ([ 'jquery', 'jquery-mouseWheel'], function () { 
    'inside code plugin mCustomScrollbar '  
 )};
```

now all files libs and plugins with one file